# Report from Git regarding branches in a release

Tags: git, bash, plugins, bitbucket-server

What is the best way to create a list of branches, that were merged into a release branch?

Is there any add-on or plugin for Stash, that a project manager could use to see which features/users stories/defects, that are part of branch names, are included into a release branch?

if there is no such plugin - which Git commands could be used to create such a report?

Comment: Are you using JIRA with Stash, by any chance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about the plugin, but you can use the following command to get the list of branches:

```
git show-branch --list
```

This documentation was pretty useful: http://git-scm.com/docs/git-show-branch.html

Hope this helped!

Comment: Thank you, this was helpful. Still hope that mAy be, someone will know something that will not require Bash commands, so that non-technical people could just press button and get nicely formatted list of branches.

Comment: I found a project that parses the output of git show-branch into objects so you can output the contents in any way you want to display to a user, check it out: https://www.npmjs.org/package/git-show-branch-parser